# $.getJSON to receive JSON from API URL

Tags: jquery, getjson

Hey I've done about as much research as I can and can't figure out my issue, if anyone could help me out.

Basically have a API set up leading to a JSON doc and something seems to be hanging up the URL and this is what I'm working with so far

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        $.getJSON('http://localhost:41387/api/v0/9405503699300197435172',
            function (json) {
                console.log(json);
            }
        );
    });
});
```

I'm taking that the request is being made and completed, but I'm not getting a response.

I know it can't be the code because I used a twitter search URL and got back a response.

There are no errors or exceptions being thrown in the server code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you put the url http://localhost:41387/api/v0/usps/9405503699300197435172 into your browser do you get any JSON back?

Comment: What happens when you execute that URL on your navigator? Do you get a JSON as a response?

Comment: The answer to those questions is yes, but for some reason I had to append ?callback=? to the url and it finally sent back the request. Anyone have an explanation?

Comment: @mgaughan: That's called [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).  You cannot request JSON from a [different domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  JSONP is not actually JSON, it's a JavaScript file that contains JSON (well, a function being called with the JSON).  `?callback=?` tells [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to use JSONP.

Comment: Your package was delivered on Tuesday, August 23, 2011 at 2:15 PM :-P

Comment: so would the better solution be to use an ajax call with type jsonp?

Comment: @mgaughan: That's what you are doing when you add `?callback=?` to your URL.  `$.getJSON` with `?callback=?` is shorthand for `$.ajax` with `dataType: 'jsonp'`.

Answer (score 0):

From reading your question and comments, I think the reason it works when you use JSONP, might have to do with cross-domain restriction set by the browser.

Make sure the page where you run ajax calls and the ajax URL are on the same domain. In this case, they both need to be on "http://localhost" domain name.